# PyQt4 - Running functions that use python 2.7.11's builtin modules in separate threads

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, pyqt4, qthread

i'm making an application for my grad paper at the university and i'm stuck with threading.
i'm trying to make an audio player that loads files into a table and plays them while taking specified intervals into account (basically sleeps after each sound played). i can get the list to play in order but it's in the same thread so GUI gets stcuk while that's happening. i used PyQt4 for the GUI because it was the fastest way to make a GUI and i'm visually impaired so i don't want to waste time coding all the UI stuff.
i've seen some QThread examples but i can't seem to get my threading to work.
i'm using winsound to play the sounds and they are loaded from an internal list which correpsonds to the table that displays on GUI
the file_list is an Ui_MainWindow instance variable (basically the main application class's variable) and all the functions are also defined in that class
Here's the relevant code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from winsound import PlaySound, SND_FILENAME
```

#some more code for the Ui_MainWindow class

```
  def play_stop(self):
      t=Create_thread(self.snd_play)        t.started.connect(func)
      t.start()


  def snd_play(self):
      if not self.is_playing:
          self.is_playing=True
          for e in self.file_list:
              PlaySound(e, SND_FILENAME)
          self.is_playing=False

class Create_thread(QtCore.QThread):

  def __init__(self,function):
      QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
      self.function=function

def run(self):
    self.function()

  def main():
    app=QtGui.QApplication([])
    window=Ui_MainWindow()
    window.setupUi(window)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I made a Create_thread class because i wanted a quick way to run functions in separate threads which is why the run function executes the function given as the argument

this worked when i was testing without GUI and with the threading module but when i introduced the GUI it stopped working and crashed my program
like i said the play_stop and snd_play are functions of the Ui_Mainwindow class
Any help would be greatly appreciated because without threading my application won't work properly.

Comment: You can still use the normal `threading` module with PyQt, and in your case I'd say that's easier.

Comment: 'Create_thread' class actually used to inherit from 'threading.Thread' but as with the 'QThread' it did not work

Answer (score 1):

i found the issue with the threading module (it was my fault, of course)
For anyone having similar issues here's the correct class code:

```
    class Create_thread(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self,function):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.function=function
        def run(self):
            self.function()
```

so i just needed to call the **init** function of the Thread class.
also here's the play_stop function code:

```
    def play_stop(self):
        t=Create_thread(self.snd_play) #calls the actual function to play
        t.start()
```

@101 thanks for your response